# EnableCustomBinding in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Hello How do EnableCustomBinding in Telerik MVC,

I know how to do it in c# but I am new to vb.net please let me know

C# code For EnableCustomBinding

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
```

How to convert above code in VB.net

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
<GridAction(EnableCustomBinding := true)>
```